# How does this whole FrameBuffer, DRM, KMS stuff work in todays Linux / Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, video, framebuffer, drm, kms

I'm confused about what is what nowadays with Linux and video support for the console interface vs X.

Do the /dev/fb* items only relate to the old original framebuffer support?

Does DRM create/support /dev/fb* items.

How does KMS fit in to all of this?

Do you still need at least the generic frame buffer support for VESA or EFI to have console support?

TIA!!

Comment: Could be what you're looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15738/kernel-mode-setting-vs-framebuffer